# Extract numeric + space / hyphen and alphanumeric values from text

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract numbers and unique identifiers from a string.

```
text = '+1 (123) 4567, 11111111, some text, 2222 2222, 333-33333-333, 444-444-444-4, some other text, 5555 5555 5555 5555 5, ab12345, xy7890z'
```

I have these regex:

```
regex_a = re.findall(r"\d+(?:[\s-]?\d+)*", text)
```

```
regex_b = re.findall(r"\(?\+[\d _\-\.\)\(\+]{8,25}[\d]{1}|\d{1,}", text)
```

```
regex_c = re.findall(r"^ (?=[a-zA-Z]+|\s+|\$)|(?:(?:[a-zA-Z]{0,}\s?\$?\s*)\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s?[a-zA-Z]{1,})$", text)
```

```
combined_regex = re.findall(r"\d+(?:[\s-]?\d+)*|\(?\+[\d _\-\.\)\(\+]{8,25}[\d]{1}|\d{1,}|^ (?=[a-zA-Z]+|\s+|\$)|(?:(?:[a-zA-Z]{0,}\s?\$?\s*)\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s?[a-zA-Z]{1,})$", text)
```

I intend to combine the 3 regexes into 1 regex. regex_c is used to extract the monetary amount of different combinations in the text. It is working for just that purpose. But I have an issue when combining the 3 regexes together.

Results from **combined regex**:

```
['+1 (123) 4567','11111111', '2222', '2222', '333','33333-333', '444,444-444-4', '5555', '5555', '5555', '5555', '5','ab12345','xy7890']
```

Results from **regex_a**:

```
['1', '123', '4567', '11111111', '2222 2222', '333-33333-333', '444-444-444-4', '5555 5555 5555 5555 5', '12345', '7890']
```

Results from **regex_b**:

```
['+1 (123) 4567', '11111111', '2222', '2222', '333', '33333', '333', '444', '444', '444', '4', '5555', '5555', '5555', '5555', '5', '12345', '7890']
```

Results from **regex_c**:

```
['1', '123', ' 4567', '11111111', ' 2222', ' 2222', ' 333', '33333', '333', ' 444', '444', '444', '4', ' 5555', ' 5555', ' 5555', ' 5555', ' 5', 'ab12345', 'xy7890']
```

**The expected output**:

```
['+1 (123) 4567','11111111', '2222 2222', '333-33333-333', '444-444-444-4', '5555 5555 5555 5555 5', 'ab12345', 'xy7890z']
```

Is there any way that I can combine the 3 regexes into 1 regex to extract the expected results and maintaining the logic for regex_c?

Comment: How does the combined regex look like (edit the question)? Should the combined and expected regex produce a list like the other regexes with `findall` do?

Comment: whaty about just: `[^,0-9-0-9]+,` - replace matched with empty string, the output will be: `+1 (123) 4567, 11111111, 2222 2222, 333-33333-333, 444-444-444-4, 5555 5555 5555 5555 5, ab12345, xy7890z`

Comment: hi @MichaelButscher, have added the combined regex. It's a combination of a, b and c. yup, it should return a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may revamp your regex a bit and use in a `re.finditer` call:

```
(?<!\w)(?:(?:\+\d{1,4}[\s-]*)?(?:\(\d+\)|\d{2,})[-\s]*\d+(?=([\s-]?))(?:\1\d+)*|(?:[a-zA-Z]+\d|\d+[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*)\b
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pu2ptu/2)

[Python code](https://ideone.com/fAUYZA):

```
import re
text = '+1 (123) 4567, 11111111, some text, 2222 2222, 333-33333-333, 444-444-444-4, some other text, 5555 5555 5555 5555 5, ab12345, xy7890z'

rx = re.compile(r'''(?<!\w)(?: # Left-hand word boundary, start of a group:
  (?:\+\d{1,4}[\s-]*)?         # Optional: `+` and 1 to 4 digits and then 0+ whitespace/-
  (?:\(\d+\)|\d{2,})           # (, 1+ digits, ), or 2 or more digits
  [-\s]*                       # 0+ whitespaces or hyphens
  \d+                          # 1+ digits, and 
  (?=([\s-]?))(?:\1\d+)*       # 0 or more sequences of optional - or whitespace and 1+ digits
|                              # or
  (?:[a-zA-Z]+\d|\d+[a-zA-Z])  # 1+ letters and then a digit, or 1+ digits and then a letter
  [a-zA-Z0-9]*                 # 0 or more letters or digits
)\b                            # End of the group, word boundary''', re.VERBOSE)

print( [x.group() for x in rx.finditer(text)] )
```

Output:

```
[
    '+1 (123) 4567',
    '11111111',
    '2222 2222',
    '333-33333-333',
    '444-444-444-4',
    '5555 5555 5555 5555 5',
    'ab12345',
    'xy7890z'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
import re

text = '+1 (123) 4567, 11111111, some text, 2222 2222, 333-33333-333, 444-444-444-4, some other text, 5555 5555 5555 5555 5, ab12345, xy7890z'

print(re.sub(r'(?:^|(?<=,))\D*(?:,|$)', '', text))
```

Output:

```
+1 (123) 4567, 11111111, 2222 2222, 333-33333-333, 444-444-444-4, 5555 5555 5555 5555 5, ab12345, xy7890z
```

Explanation of the regex `(?:^|(?<=,))\D*(?:,|$)`:

```
(?:^|(?<=,)) ... positive lookbehind which matches the beginning of the string or a leading comma
\D*          ... zero or more sequence of non-digit characters
(?:,|$)      ... a comma or the end of the string
```